# Ошибка "Unknown column in 'where clause' "

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Ситуация: есть таблица, которая связана еще с несколькими по ключу. В основной таблице находится id города (ID_City), в связанной - сам город (City). В запросе необходимо связать обе таблицы и выводить записи из основной таблицы, содержащие только конкретный город. Таблицы связаны следующим образом:

```html
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ((trequestdriver INNER JOIN tarea ON `trequestdriver`.`ID_Area` = `tarea`.`ID_Area`) INNER JOIN tcity ON `trequestdriver`.`ID_City` = `tcity`.`ID_City`) INNER JOIN taddress ON `trequestdriver`.`ID_АddressStart` = `taddress`.`ID_Address` WHERE `ID_Person` = '$iddr' AND `City` = '$citydr' ORDER BY  `trequestdriver`.`ID_RequestDriver`") or die (mysql_error());
```

При попытки выполнение появляется ошибка Unknown column 'City' in 'where clause'. Как я понимаю, несмотря на связь таблиц через запрос, при попытке произвести выборку по городам из связанной таблицы, запрос не срабатывает.

Comment: Думаю это из за скобок во from. все что внутри скобок для внешних частей запроса под именами таблиц уже не доступно. Но в вашем запросе только inner join и скобки вообще не нужны, уберите их и думаю все станет нормально. Либо у вас в таблицах действительно нет поля с таким именем. Обратите внимание, когда имя поля заключено в обратные апострофы регистр букв в названии должен точно соответствовать тому, что в таблице

Comment: Попробовала убрать скобки, ошибка та же. Поле есть 100%, ведь если убрать условие города, ниже по запросу " echo'<td>'.$row["City"].'</td>'; " он прекрасно выводит все города.

Comment: Хм. чудеса какие то. Я бы в таком случае проверял сам запрос в MySQL, потом проверял бы выборку только из таблицы где есть это поле, что бы понять как писать условие. может без обратных кавычек, может все таки какие то требования по регистру букв нарушены ...

Comment: Сейчас еще раз пересмотрела код и нашла ошибку, она была связана со второй частью запроса, но, в любом случае, спасибо за ответы)